# String parsing from a file

Tags: c, string, struct

I have a file customers.txt it is contain customers names shoping date and market name at a line in between "--";

**customers.txt**

```
Yusuf Sevki Gunaydin--11/02/2018--MARKS AND SPENCER
Mert Lacinkaya--24/02/2018--VAKKO
Elif Gul--13/05/2017--TEKIN ACAR
Hatice Cataloluk--12/07/2017--SIEMENS
```

I want to read it from file and store in a struct and viewing. all detail added.

```
typedef struct customer
{
    const char *name;
    const char *date;
    const char *marketPlace;

}customer;

int main( void ){
   FILE * file = fopen("customers.txt","r");
   customer wcustomers[25];

   if (file == NULL){
      puts("File not found !!!");
   }
   else{
    readFile(file,wcustomers);
   }
    for(int i=0; i<3 ; ++i){
       printf("%s  %s  %s\n",
          wcustomers[i].name,
          wcustomers[i].date,
          wcustomers[i].marketPlace);
    }

   return 0;
 }

 void readFile(FILE *fp, customer wcustomers[]){
   char a[50],b[50],c[50];
   size_t i=0;

   while(fscanf(fp ,"%[^--]%*s%[^--]%*s%[^\n]%*s",a,b,c) != EOF){
       wcustomers[i].name = a;
       wcustomers[i].date = b;
       wcustomers[i].marketPlace = c;
       i++;  
   }
}
```

But every iteration at while loop program just read first line and there is a disorder.Can ı handle it when scaning file or after scaning is there strip change that can I do?

**output**

```
��J'�   1 SUPERSTORE
Yusuf Evren Aykac   JEAN'S COFFEES
��J'�   1 SUPERSTORE
Yusuf Evren Aykac   JEAN'S COFFEES
��J'�   1 SUPERSTORE
Yusuf Evren Aykac   JEAN'S COFFEES
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far and what specific problems did you encounter?

Comment: Hello, Would appreciate if you could add more details about what you're doing? Asking straightaway for solutions is not considered good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the file line by line with fgets, and split each line up with strtok:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct customer
{
    const char *name;
    const char *date;
    const char *marketPlace;

}customer;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char const* const fileName = argv[1];
    FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "r");
    char line[256];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        const char s[2] = "--";
        char *token;
        customer c;

        token = strtok(str, s);
        if (token == NULL){
            printf("parsing error/n");
            exit(1);
        }
        c.name = malloc(strlen(token)+1);
        strcpy(c.name, token);

        token = strtok(str, s);
        if (token == NULL){
            printf("parsing error/n");
            exit(1);
        }
        c.date = malloc(strlen(token)+1);
        strcpy(c.date, token);

        token = strtok(str, s);
        if (token == NULL){
            printf("parsing error/n");
            exit(1);
        }
        c.marketPlace = malloc(strlen(token)+1);
        strcpy(c.marketPlace, token);
        
        processCustomer(&c);
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

In this example, the Customer c variable is only in the scope of the while loop, so it exists long enough to call some external function like processCustomer(), but you could also create an array of customer structs and populate them one by one with each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in more than one way.

For example, you can load the whole content of the file to memory using `mmap`, and then go over the memory map and parse it using `strtok`.

Comment: If you use `mmap`, then `strtok` will alter the original file without special options to `mmap`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do it with [strtok](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm). You can scan file line by line using fgets and then use strtok to split get `name`, `date` and `marketPlace` Here is an example to populate array of `customer` while scanning file line by line:

```c
// Read File
FILE *pFile = fopen("customers.txt", "r");
if(pFile == NULL) {
    perror("Unable to open file!");
    exit(1);
}

char line[100];
customer customers[100];
char delim[3] = "--";
int nCustomers = 0;
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), pFile) != NULL) {
    // Trim trailing newline added by fgets
    line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0;
    
    // Name
    char *token = strtok(line, delim);
    char *name = (char *) malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
    strcpy(name, token);

    // Date
    token = strtok(NULL, delim);
    char *date = (char *) malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
    strcpy(date, token);

    // MarketPlace
    token = strtok(NULL, delim);
    char *marketPlace = (char *) malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
    strcpy(marketPlace, token);

    customers[nCustomers].name = name;
    customers[nCustomers].date = date;
    customers[nCustomers].marketPlace = marketPlace;
    nCustomers++;
}
```

Comment: Mallocing a fixed 50 bytes wastes space, and will break if the string is ever longer than 49 chars. It is preferable to allocate the exact size you need with malloc(strlen(token)+1).

Comment: You're right. Thanks a lot for your review. I've updated my answer